# Connecting play framework to mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions, playframework-2.0, user-permissions, database-permissions

I have two databases in mysql:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| app                |
| app_dev            |
+--------------------+
```

I have two play framework servers running, one using app and one using app_dev. The server connecting to app is local to the machine running mysql. The server connecting to app_dev is remote. I think I've setup the permissions correctly:

```
mysql> show grants for 'app_dev';
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for app_dev@%                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'app_dev'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pwd' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `app_dev`.* TO 'app_dev'@'%'             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> show grants for 'app'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for app@localhost                                             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'app'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'pwd' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `app`.* TO 'app'@'localhost'                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Yet for some reason, when I try to start play on my development machine, I get the response: MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'app_dev'@'2.ipn.ipn.ipn' for table 'play_evolutions'.

Is it possible I've set up the permissions incorrectly? The only thing that's different here is the need for the % sign as this is a remote connection!

Comment: did you check the firewall might be the port issue

Comment: I have no idea what happened here in the end - I went back after a while and it worked, maybe it was some firewall issue, or a mysql bounce or something??